# How to swap selected datagridview row

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a datagridview called dgvNoveStavke and I add a row to it every time I press a button in my form like this:

```
private void btnDodajStavke_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  DataGridViewRow red = (DataGridViewRow)dgvNoveStavke.Rows[0].Clone();
  red.Cells[0].Value = txtIdStavke.Text;
  red.Cells[1].Value = txtIzabranaStavka.Text;
  red.Cells[2].Value = txtKolicina.Text;
  red.Cells[3].Value = txtPopust.Text;
  dgvNoveStavke.Rows.Add(red);
}
```

When I click a row in my datagrid view I fill the textboxes with the data in the row and I enable the buttons to edit and delete the row like this:

```
private void dgvNoveStavke_SelectionChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  txtIdStavke.Text = dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[0].Value.ToString();
  txtIzabranaStavka.Text = dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[1].Value.ToString();
  txtKolicina.Text = dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[2].Value.ToString();
  txtPopust.Text = dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[3].Value.ToString();
  btnObrisiStavku.Enabled = true;
  btnUrediStavku.Enabled = true;
}
```

I dont know how to swap the old row with the new row I create when I press the edit button.

```
private void btnUrediStavku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{         
  DataGridViewRow red = (DataGridViewRow)dgvNoveStavke.Rows[0].Clone();
  red.Cells[0].Value = txtIdStavke.Text;
  red.Cells[1].Value = txtIzabranaStavka.Text;
  red.Cells[2].Value = txtKolicina.Text;
  red.Cells[3].Value = txtPopust.Text;
  // how do I replace the selected row with the new one I created here
}
```

I tried using

```
dgvNoveStavke.SelectedRows[0] = red;
```

But that doesnt work and I dont know what else to try, could anyone tell how I can swap or replace the row i selected in datagridview.

EDIT:
Figured it out!
I just selected every cell I had an set the new value for them. 
This is the code:

```
private void btnUrediStavku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (dgvNoveStavke.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
            {
                dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[0].Value = txtIdStavke.Text;
                dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[1].Value = txtIzabranaStavka.Text;
                dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[2].Value = txtKolicina.Text;
                dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[3].Value = txtPopust.Text;
            }      
        }
```

Comment: Just tried it and the same error happens

Comment: Have you tried to copy values, delete row, then add a new row with those values?

Comment: Just a thought: Have you tried editing the underlying data source directly and refreshing/updating the view when you're done? Maybe it's easier to do it this way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

selected every cell I had an set the new value for them. This is the code:

```
private void btnUrediStavku_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (dgvNoveStavke.SelectedRows.Count > 0)
   {
       dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[0].Value = txtIdStavke.Text;
       dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[1].Value = txtIzabranaStavka.Text;
       dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[2].Value = txtKolicina.Text;
       dgvNoveStavke.SelectedCells[3].Value = txtPopust.Text;
   }      
}
```